# Telerik Grid - Get master ID in details view

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid

I have a master/detail grid where I do inserts on both the master and detail views.  When I'm in detail mode, I need to obtain the master ID value but I can't seem to obtain the value.

I first obtain the `inserteditem` in the `InsertCommand`:

```
Dim inserteditem As GridDataInsertItem = DirectCast(e.Item, GridDataInsertItem)
```

And then I obtain an instance of the parent (master) view:

```
Dim parenttable As GridTableView = inserteditem.OwnerTableView.ParentItem.OwnerTableView
```

I just can't seem to get to the master key value, however.  Anyone know what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

.ASPX

```
    <MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="Top" DataKeyNames="ID" Name="parent">
        <DetailTables>
            <telerik:GridTableView Name="Child" DataKeyNames="Name">
            </telerik:GridTableView>
        </DetailTables>
        <Columns>
           ........
           ........
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
```

.ASPX.VB

```
Protected Sub RadGrid1_InsertCommand(sender As Object, e As GridCommandEventArgs)
If e.Item.OwnerTableView.Name = "Child" Then
    Dim item As GridDataInsertItem = TryCast(e.Item, GridDataInsertItem)
    Dim pitem As GridDataItem = TryCast(item.OwnerTableView.ParentItem, GridDataItem)
        ' Parent Item DataKey Here
    Dim strID As String = pitem.GetDataKeyValue("ID").ToString()
End If
End Sub
```